# laravel automatically deletes server.php on php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using laravel 5.6 on windows environment using php 7.2, (installed with xampp).After installing laravel the 'php artisan serve' command work but automatically deletes the server.php file .

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23809

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to avoid the answer to this getting buried, OP linked issue solution in the comment [Link explaining issue and how to resolve](http://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23809)

User had Avast antivirus running and it incorrectly flagged server.php as a malicious file, adding an exception to Avast for that file resolved the issue.

Comment: I am not installing avast .but server.php deletes when i run php artisan serve.My laravel version is 6.x.Help me..

Comment: Yes but in my case I need also reboot the PC.

Answer (score 3):

Add the server.php as exception for Avast.

It seems that you have used Avast Antivirus in your system. It detects it as thread.

Comment: No it is not enough. You have to stop Avast, then run git revert and then create exception.

Answer (score 1):

For me :

When Avast antivirus running flagged server.php as a malicious file change this in menu - parameter - exclusions 
and change a line in server.php

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri))
```

to

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'laraveltest/public'.$uri))
```